# Tomcat web application changing deployment directories

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, web, deployment

suppose I have the follow war files: test1.war, test2.war, and I want to deploy both of them on tomcat server

What I want to do is to put them up on localhost:8080/test1, for test1.war, and localhost:8080/test2, for test2.war

This would have been easily accomplished just by moving the two war files into webapps directory, HOWEVER, I need to put the directories like this:

- apache-tomcat-7.0.50

  - webapps

    - test1

      - WAR file
      - Exploded files
    - test2

      - WAR file
      - Exploded files

As you can see, I have specific folder requirements, so just throwing those two WAR files into webapps folder is not gona cut it.

I can also modify server.xml, or add test.xml and test2.xml into tomcat/conf/Catalina/locahost, however, doing this allows the WAR file to be put into the right directories, but I can't change where the exploded files will be.

A third option is to use multiple hosts in server.xml. So one host for test1, one host for test2. However, that means I must use two ports for localhost, say localhost:8080 and localhost:8081, and that is not allowed.

How then, am I supposed to do this? To sum it up, I want to have that folder structure:

- apache-tomcat-7.0.50

  - webapps

    - test1

      - WAR file
      - Exploded files
    - test2

      - WAR file
      - Exploded files

to deploy test1.WAR and test2.WAR, and they MUST use the same port, so for instance they must both use localhost:8080/test1, and localhost:8080/test2, no multiple ports

Comment: Why do you need such a folder structure?

Comment: lets just say my supervisor likes that folder structure

Comment: What??? Tell your supervisor that sometimes he has to live with disappointment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the default tomcat config, and use symbolic links to relocate files and folders to where you really need them.

Example:

You have that "Webapps" folder {somwehere}

- Webapps (real folder)

  - test1 (real folder)

    - WAR file (real file)
    - Exploded files (symlink to tomcat/webapps/test1)
  - test2 (real folder)

    - WAR file (real file)
    - Exploded files (symlink to tomcat/webapps/test2)

Then under tomcat you'd have:

- tomcat (tomcat install)

  - webapps (the real tomcat webapps folder)

    - test1.war (symlink to {somewhere}/Webapps/test1/test1.war)
    - test2.war (symlink to {somewhere}/Webapps/test2/test2.war)

Comment: yes but, what needs to happen is the first webapps directory structure in the tomcat install folder, so for instance, test1.WAR must be in tomcat->webapps->test1->test1.WAR, and test1 exploded folder must be in tomcat->webapps->test1->test1, and test2.WAR must be in tomcat->webapps->test2->test2.WAR and so on

Comment: using symlinks as i've described will work fine in that situation.  You will have files/links in both places (tomcat default area, and where you want them).  It will *not* work if you're also trying to keep the webapps folder itself clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two hosts and mapp different webapp directories:

```
<Host appBase="webapps/test1" name="test1" unpackWARs="true" ...>
<Host appBase="webapps/test2" name="test2" unpackWARs="true" ...>
```